# BigCommerce Api v3 Channels List Api filter by name doesn't work

Tags: bigcommerce

I am testing this bigcommerce api v3 documentation and channels listing filter by name doesn't work.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/channels/channels/listchannels

Here it has the option to filter by name but it doesn't work.
Any idea about this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SkyDev. Thank you for bringing this to our attention. You are correct that this endpoint does not support filtering with the name query parameter. We are actively working on updating the docs to accurately display this. Thanks!